# To extract a set of feature and cluster data from the given point cloud data

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-7, point-cloud-library

Presently I am using PCL 1.8.0, we are having a sample cloud data of a plate which has some of the components fitted on the plate which are of few centimeters above on the actual plate.

This is the cloud data with the cluster and features data.
[Cloud Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5twf.jpg)

By using the Euclidean cluster extraction, I am able to get the cluster count and cluter shapes from the sample data and these clusters are saved into to a different PCD depending on the cluster data and shape as shown below.
[Extracted Cluster Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fBxk.jpg)

Now if u observe in the above image we are getting only the outer boundary of the cluster as per my requirement, I want the entire outer boundary and inner features of the cluster to be written to a separate PCD file, for further calculation,

Can any one suggest me on how to extract the cluster and the feature data from the given cloud data and write it to a separate PCD files.

Any suggestion will be helpful

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to your problem:

1. Compute the clusters as you're already doing.
2. Pick the cluster that you're interested in.
3. Compute the [minimum oriented bounding box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box) containing your cluster.
4. Use the computed box to clip the original point cloud, getting all the points within the box.

The process to compute the minimum oriented bounding box is described on the [PCL forums](http://www.pcl-users.org/Finding-oriented-bounding-box-of-a-cloud-td4024616.html). However, here's an outline of the solution by Nicola Fioraio, for convenience and further references:

> 1) compute the centroid (c0, c1, c2) and the normalized covariance
>
> 2) compute the eigenvectors e0, e1, e2. The reference system will be (e0, e1, e0 X e1) --- note: e0 X e1 = +/- e2
>
> 3) move the points in that RF --- note: the transformation given by the rotation matrix (e0, e1, e0 X e1) & (c0, c1, c2) must be inverted
>
> 4) compute the max, the min and the center of the diagonal
>
> 5) given a box centered at the origin with size (max_pt.x - min_pt.x, max_pt.y - min_pt.y, max_pt.z - min_pt.z) the transformation you have to apply is Rotation = (e0, e1, e0 X e1) & Translation = Rotation * center_diag + (c0, c1, c2)

Comment: Hi Dexter, Firstly Thanks for your reply, As u have suggested i will make the  minimum oriented bounding box which is possible with PCL, after making the box how should i extract the features from my main cloud. Is it possible? If possible can u please suggest any way on how to extract the specified feature, Any suggestion will be helpfull and grateful, thank u

Comment: You can get the indices of the points that fall inside the the mOBB and use them to pick the features that you have computed. Also, if you found the previous answer helpful, please make sure to accept it :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I am tried to mark u r answer but due to low reputation i couldn't mark your answer

Answer (score 0):

Firstly thanks for your suggestion.

As you have suggested with PCA and Bounding box I have created a bounding box and I am also able to view the created box in the PCL Visualizer, now after getting the bounding box now my aim is to save the generated Cube to a separate PCD file for further calculations.

Here is the code that I am using for the generation of the Bounding Box, can any suggest me on how to save the generated Cube to a separate PCD file

```
int BoundingBox(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr point_cloud_ptr)
{

   // compute principal direction
   Eigen::Vector4f centroid;
   pcl::compute3DCentroid(*point_cloud_ptr, centroid);
   Eigen::Matrix3f covariance;
   computeCovarianceMatrixNormalized(*point_cloud_ptr, centroid,covariance);
   Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Eigen::Matrix3f> eigen_solver(covariance,  Eigen::ComputeEigenvectors);
   Eigen::Matrix3f eigDx = eigen_solver.eigenvectors();
   eigDx.col(2) = eigDx.col(0).cross(eigDx.col(1));

   // move the points to the that reference frame
   Eigen::Matrix4f p2w(Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity());
   p2w.block<3,3>(0,0) = eigDx.transpose();
   p2w.block<3,1>(0,3) = -1.f * (p2w.block<3,3>(0,0) * centroid.head<3>());
   pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cPoints;
   pcl::transformPointCloud(*point_cloud_ptr, cPoints, p2w);

   pcl::PointXYZ min_pt, max_pt;
   pcl::getMinMax3D(cPoints, min_pt, max_pt);
   const Eigen::Vector3f mean_diag = 0.5f*(max_pt.getVector3fMap() + min_pt.getVector3fMap());

   // final transform
   const Eigen::Quaternionf qfinal(eigDx);
   const Eigen::Vector3f tfinal = eigDx*mean_diag + centroid.head<3>();

   // draw the cloud and the box
   pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer;
   viewer.addPointCloud(point_cloud_ptr);
   viewer.addCube(tfinal, qfinal, max_pt.x - min_pt.x, max_pt.y - min_pt.y, max_pt.z - min_pt.z);
   viewer.spin();

   return(0);
  }
```

Any Suggestion will be helpful.
Thanks in Advance